# middleware and stack functions invoker for expressjs and the response object capture

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I see that expressjs app has a `stack` of `Layer` object Arrays. Which is the function that is used to pass the

I want to know:

- When a request is sent from the `http` client which `function is invoked first` and how is the stack array functions with `middlewares` invoked and results passed stepwise?
- Here is an example `app.get(path, [middleware(req, res, next), m2(req, res, next), m3(req, res, next), m4(req, res, next)], handler(req, res))` => which function invokes functions stepwise => `[middleware(req, res, next), m2(req, res, next), m3(req, res, next), m4(req, res, next), handler(req, res)]`
- Where is the `request` and `response` objects created that is passed as `arguments`?
- Where is the `response` object callback function for `send` => `onfinish`/ `onend` functions which I can use to get the `send`/ `sendfile's` response object into a `variable` for an `interceptor`?

I am looking for the entry of the request and exit if the response (with the response result).

Comment: All of the code for Express is [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express) and all these questions can be answered by studying the code and understanding how it works since you're basically just asking how Express does what it does internally.  I'd suggest you do some of that work yourself and then post back here if you have more specific questions about what exactly the code is doing and then you can reference the actual relevant piece of code in your new question.

Comment: i have done that. i did a debug but there seems to be a issue. the routes module or the layer instances cannot be invoked or passed by; the next() fails. I understand that middlwares.init() gets all middlewares initialised. but is there a way for just using the router module for matching my own path provided to the function?

Comment: The router module does not provide a means to match your own paths for your own purposes.  It uses the `path-to-regexp` module which you could also use for your own purposes.  You can see all the modules it uses here: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/package.json.  Other than this, I can't really tell what else you're asking.

Comment: no i do not want to match my own paths. what i want to know is `where` in the application.js or the express framework is the list of all `middlewares and callbacks invoked`? What is the start point and what is the end point. I did notice the `onend` function, but i was unable to get the response object captured. I wanted to knw the entry and exit points for the express `req` and `res` object when a request is received.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?  Right now, you're asking a bunch of "how does it work" questions, but not describing what the actual problem is which cuts off our ability to just offer you a good solution to whatever the actual problem is.

Comment: no my question is the same and simple i want the function entry point of req object and exit point of res object so. i actually repeated myself again in different ways 3 times. i am unsure why that was not understandable.

Comment: Because that's not a problem you're trying to solve.  That is apparently your guess at how you would solve some problem (making this an XY question which severely limits people's ability to help you solve the actual problem).  But, that isn't how Express is designed to be used so I was thinking that if you described the actual problem, I could perhaps suggest a supported way to solve the problem.  If you want to go about hacking Express in unsupported ways, your best bet is to just study the code and figure out how it works internally.

Comment: Also, `req` and `res` are objects created by the `http` or `https` interface that is built into nodejs and to which Express uses and extends.  They don't have entry and exit points because they're objects with methods, not functions.

Comment: yes they are Req and Res objects. i am looking at the entry and exit function points to invoke routes and middlewares. i looked at application.js, could notfigure the exact point of invocation

Comment: So, you were super active engaging with me and then I wrote an answer and you went completely silent?  How come?

Comment: here is the express codebase without server `https://github.com/ganeshkbhat/loadbalancer/blob/main/demos/express-app.js` and here is what I was working on `https://github.com/ganeshkbhat/loadbalancer/blob/dbabf03c0920c6aa71badeec170136680da5951b/src/serverutils.js#LL83C13-L83C13`. give me a few times, will revert, testing it. i wanted to avoid a proxy server to use request response without an external proxy server. pls keep it top secret, it is in development. it is first of its kind.

Comment: Did I not answer the question you asked?

Comment: the `app.handle()` is failing somewhere in my way of usage. checking.

Comment: even when i am looking at the supertest function, it `is` creating a testing http server within itself. https://github.com/ladjs/supertest/blob/c1b8f9da7b58a5ffe6bf6a1b5056435a21d3c365/index.js#LL35C1-L35C1 so technically the HttpRequest and HttpResponse object is created not manually but using the actual request send via the supertestagent

Comment: As I've already said, `req` and `res` are created by the `http.createSserver()` internals when an incoming http request arrives and they are then passed to the callback that you pass `http.createServer()`.  You do not create them yourself.  I have no idea what this question is about any more.  I've answered what you have in your question.  If you have something else you want to ask about the code you linked above, then you should accept the answer here and write a new question about whatever else you want to ask.

Comment: If you don't think I've answered what you have in your original question, then please be specific about what that you wrote in your original question isn't yet answered.  You can't just turn this question into a running conversation about what isn't working in your code.  That's not how stackoverflow works.  Ask one question, get an answer.  If you have more questions, write a new question.

Comment: no. you answered my question; yes partially for my question though; the other part which is not supposed to be part of the question anyways. I just wanted the `entry` and `exit` points of the `req`, `res`. I will create a `Request` and `Response` object manually. I am not looking to create a `req`, and `res` object through `http.createServer()` at all which is why I wanted to know the `RequestObject` entry and `ResponseObject` exit points. the app.handle did not work exactly as I wanted. even the supertest internally creates a http server to send and fetch req, res is what i wanted to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code for `app.listen()` [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/0debedf4f31bb20203da0534719b9b10d6ac9a29/lib/application.js#L633), you see this:

```
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

So, it is registering the `app` function object as a callback to `http.createServer()`.  That will call the app function which is [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/0debedf4f31bb20203da0534719b9b10d6ac9a29/lib/express.js#L38) for any incoming http request and that function looks like this:

```
var app = function(req, res, next) {
  app.handle(req, res, next);
};
```

Yes, this is a bit of weird design where the `app` object is actually a function (since functions are objects too), but that's the way Express did it.

So, the start of any routing is `app.handle()` [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/0debedf4f31bb20203da0534719b9b10d6ac9a29/lib/application.js#L165), which then ends up calling `router.handle()` [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/0debedf4f31bb20203da0534719b9b10d6ac9a29/lib/router/index.js#L136) which then starts working with the layer objects to match defined routes.

---

You really shouldn't have to dive into any of this for anything other than curiosity.  I have been able to do all sorts of custom things with Express by either listening to events that are already being fired on the `req` or `res` objects (such as when the request is done) or by overriding methods to intercept or modify or enhance functionality.  All of this can be done from outside the source code and the private data structures of Express.

This is why I was asking you to describe your actual problem because there's a high likelihood that you don't have to go underneath the covers of Express into its private data structures to solve most actual problems.  The public events and methods are quite capable.

Comment: Is it possible for me to run the req-res function without using the creation of http/s server using this https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/0debedf4f31bb20203da0534719b9b10d6ac9a29/lib/application.js#L633

Comment: I will create a request from fetch request (wish to mock this instead of fetch api https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/0debedf4f31bb20203da0534719b9b10d6ac9a29/lib/request.js#L31 ) and response from this object - https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/0debedf4f31bb20203da0534719b9b10d6ac9a29/lib/response.js#L43 to run the `router.handle(req, res, next)`

Comment: `request` `>` request object `>`  `app (with routes, without listening)` `>` process request to `get response` through `route handler` `>` `response` - is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @gary - All these comments are defining some additional question that is not part of your original question.  I'd suggest you write a new question and fully describe what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: ok. any help is welcome to get the middlewares and routes running without a listening server. here is the new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76401775/run-middlewares-and-handler-of-express-app-with-routes-and-get-response-without